# How to pass more arguments to scheduler?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scheduler

I am studying the example [in this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler), but I am not sure how the scheduler function is receiving both the epoch and learning rate (lr). How are they being passed? And how can I pass more arguments?

I tried following this example and I received an error that says scheduler received an extra argument "lr", so I am not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually use [tf.keras.optimizers.schedules](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules) and pass them directly to the model optimizer. The link you are referring to is actually a `callback` that needs some kind of scheduler function. Here is an example of an `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay` function according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules):

```py
initial_learning_rate = 0.1
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=100000,
    decay_rate=0.96,
    staircase=True)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler) shows you a good example of how to use a custom callable, which uses the initial learning rate defined in the optimizer. In this case, it is [0.01](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD).